# Incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine, GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I had an old project kind off like a POC 2-3 years old in flutter,
Now when I try to run it on the latest version I get the following error:

On Flutter Run:

```
/Users/jci/Documents/Projects/Flutter/dicee/android/app/src/main/java/co/appbrewery/dicee/MainActivity.java:11: error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
                                           ^
Note: /Users/jci/Documents/Projects/Flutter/dicee/android/app/src/main/java/co/appbrewery/dicee/MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Flutter Run -v:

```
[   +1 ms] /Users/jci/Documents/Projects/Flutter/dicee-flutter/android/app/src/main/java/co/appbrewery/dicee/MainActivity.java:11: error: incompatible types:
MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine
[   +2 ms]     GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
[        ]                                            ^
[        ] Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
[        ] 1 error
[        ] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
[        ] > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 3s
[        ] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[        ] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[        ] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[        ] 17 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 12 up-to-date
[ +379 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 4.3s)

[+2421 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +1 ms] "flutter run" took 21,908ms.
[   +3 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:699:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1183:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

Not quite certain if it's a single error or multiple, my guess is it has something to do with my gradle any help whatsoever is appreciated.

It's been a while since I have not checked flutter so I am not sure what the error means...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After putting in some hours into this I realized that the issue was with my Activity having the old flutter engine config code, to fix this all i had to do was go from this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  }
}
```

where it was registering PluginRegistrant to that:

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

}
```

More information in the [Flutter Github Upgradation document](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects)